# Is there a way to send an invite to event via Google calendar API without customer authentication

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm looking at the Google APIs docs here: https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/nodejs and here: https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert#node.js
and in both cases - unless I'm doing something which is likely - I get asked to authorise the request, but I was wondering if there is a way to send a calendar invite without the authorisation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the documentation page [events insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert#node.js) you will notice the following

[image]

This means that the method uses private user data and requires authorization in order to use it.   You can not create a event without having access to the calendar.

Comment: @DalmTo Do you know if its possible to have our own calendar to create events in it, which would allow send invites to third parties without asking the third parties to authorise?

Comment: as long as you have access to the calendar itself then you have access to invite people to it, you just need their email.